# A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in XXXX

Tags: .net, webassembly, avalonia

I want to use .net 7.0 + avalonia 11 to develope a webapp in Windows. "dotnet" does not work well.

I followed [Avalonia running in browser](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/tutorials/running-in-the-browser) to initialize a demo. "dotnet build" and "dotnet run" works very well. However, I want to apply "dotnet publish" to assemblize the app. It never succeed in Visual Studio.

If I apply command in cmd, I get
[no succeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSZnz.png),
there is no succeded.

Moerover, if I apply "dotnet Test.Browser.dll" to "bin/Debug/...../Test.Browser.dll", then "A fatal ..." is returned.